# Consume from multiple rabbit queue shards using spring-rabbit

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a rabbit cluster (3 nodes) with a sharded queue. each shard resides on a different rabbit broker node.
I'm using spring rabbit module to consume messages from the sharded queue, however, the consumer is always connected (and consumes) from a single rabbit node (and therefore, shard).
I have set the cache mode to 'connection', so multiple connections can be opened, I'm using the spring.rabbitmq.addresses property, to pass multiple addresses for the spring connection factory but still get a connection for a single node (first one on the list)

this is my spring configuration:

```java
 @Bean
    DirectRabbitListenerContainerFactory directRabbitListenerContainerFactory(
            DirectRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        DirectRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new DirectRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        Advice[] adviceChain = { retryInterceptor() };
        factory.setAdviceChain(adviceChain);
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RetryOperationsInterceptor retryInterceptor() {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
                .maxAttempts(retriesOnError)
                .build();
    }
```

and this is my application.yaml:

```yaml
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: node1:5672,node2:5672,node3:5672
    username: ${RABBITMQ_USERNAME}
    password: ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}
    listener:
    cache:
      connection:
        mode: connection
      type: direct
      direct:
        acknowledge-mode: auto
        consumers-per-queue: ${RABBITMQ_CONSUMERS_PER_QUEUE}
```

and this is my rabbit listener:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class RabbitMQConsumer {

    private final MessageAction postProcessAction;
    private final ComponentService componentService;
    private final Coercion coercion;

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${spring.rabbitmq.queueName}", containerFactory = "directRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen(@Payload MyObject in) {
        ///do something
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask on the rabbitmq-users Google Group, but I don't think this is a limitation of Spring, but the amqp-client itself.

My understanding from a quick read is that you consume from a "pseudo-queue" rather than the individual shards. So there is only one consumer, not 3.

You could configure 3 connection factories, 3 listener container factories and add 3 `@RabbitListener`s to the method.

**EDIT**

Also see:

```java
/**
 * When {@link #setAddresses(String) addresses} are provided and there is more than
 * one, set to true to shuffle the list before opening a new connection so that the
 * connection to the broker will be attempted in random order.
 * @param shuffleAddresses true to shuffle the list.
 * @since 2.1.8
 * @see Collections#shuffle(List)
 */
public void setShuffleAddresses(boolean shuffleAddresses) {
    this.shuffleAddresses = shuffleAddresses;
}
```

on the connection factory. Together with cache mode CONNECTION and multiple concurrency on the listener, you should hit all brokers.

Comment: Its not that i want to read from individual shards, it just that the consumer is not getting any msgs from shards that are on a node that he is not connected to.
I would probably have to duplicate connections and factories as you suggested. the thing is, 3 is not a constant so i cant create only 3, i would need to create n of each. i cant also use @RabbitListner if it needs to be created dynamically right?

Comment: You can create `RabbitListener`s programmatically - see `Programmatic Endpoint Registration` under [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#async-annotation-driven).  Use a `MethodRabbitListenerEndpoint` to point to your listener method.

Comment: Thanks Gary i will try that.  Do you have any clue why reading from a sharded queue doesn't work with a single connection?

Comment: I am not familiar with the plugin, but the readme says `How does it work? The plugin will chose the queue from the shard with the least amount of consumers, provided the queue contents are local to the broker you are connected to.` So it seems to be by design. As I said, use the `rabbitmq-users` Google Group for questions about RabbitMQ itself.

Comment: I've just remembered that the connection factory has a `shuffleAddresses` property - the shuffle is random so you are still not guaranteed to hit all 3 brokers - but if you increase he concurrency on the `RabbitListener`, there's a good chance you will (assuming cachemode CONNECTION).

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/1243 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/1242.

Comment: Can you tell on which spring-amqp version this PR's will be public?

Comment: It's currently in 2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT; the next 2.3 milestone is due in a couple of weeks or so with GA in late Oct, early Nov; but they are small changes, so I could be convinced to back-port them and include them in the next release (2.2.11).

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated.